# Precedent of country that did teaching reform: reducing number of teachers and increasing salaries

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if following question would be a right fit here,

I am looking for a Precedent of a country that would have done a school reform: from many teachers with minimal salaries to a fewer teachers with bigger salaries and how did it work out..

Comment: What school? Primary? Secondary? High school? University?

Comment: [Help Center -> What topics can I ask about here?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) : please do not ask questions about
•Undergraduate-specific issues that could not apply to graduate or post-graduate academicians

Comment: Not exactly what you look for, but Italy has done the following reform: from not enough teachers with minimal salaries to even fewer teachers with even lower salaries.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano lol, I can predict how it worked out...

Comment: @scaaahu Hi,  *What school? Primary? Secondary? High school? University?* University. But I am preeeety sure it would work out same way done at any level of education...